# Why use titles like 'Dark Knight' and 'Man of Steel'?

Tags: title, the-dark-knight, man-of-steel, comic-adaptation, dc-extended-universe

In recent Christopher Nolan's related DC films, lesser known titles are selected as movie names. Such as *Dark Knight* for *Batman* and *Man of Steel* for *Superman*.

Is there any specific reason for it or is it just to keep them separate from the previous films of Superman and Batman?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Superman

Director Zack Snyder had a marketing campaign arranged with the National Guard to promote their "Soldier of Steel" recruitment program.

You can visit the website for the program here.

http://www.soldierofsteel.com/

The marketing program was a join effort that allowed the produces of "Man of Steel" additional exposure for the film. I'm not sure if the name of the film pre-existed the campaign, but it's clear that the two are connected. I don't think the title "Superman" would have offered as much flexibility with the campaign.

### Batman

Wikipedia states this about the title.

> On July 31, 2006, Warner Bros. officially announced initiation of production for the sequel to Batman Begins titled The Dark Knight; it is the first live-action Batman film without the word "Batman" in its title, which Bale noted as signaling that "this take on Batman of mine and Chris' is very different from any of the others."

He simply wanted to differentiate his work from that of others.

Comment: The first part sounds completely unrelated. It's rather that the *Soldier of Steel* was named after the *Man of Steel* and not the other way around. And likewise it's equally unlikely that *Man of Steel* was just chosen for the ability to facilitate a good name for the campaign.

Comment: wait a second: wasn't Superman already known as The Man of Steel from the comics since long time before this movie? From the comics?

Answer (score 10):

I'd just say it is to seem like something fresh, a new take on an established role and thus using their lesser known (yet still common and recognizable by experts) nicknames rather than their original names, which have been used to great lengths already. Who wants to see yet another *Superman* or *Batman* movie nowadays?

Instead *Man of Steel* or *Dark Knight* sounds like something different and I think that is quite related to their reboot character, since both movies rather present a completely new take on those stories (Ok, *Dark Knight* was the sequel to *Batman Begins*, but so what) rather than continuing the old ones and thus being just another *Batman Continues* or *Superman VI* (forgive me for possibly getting those numbers wrong, see what I mean ;)). This is just related to nowadays' popular reboot method of taking a common and established figure and reinventing it (likewise the new *Spider-Man* is not fourth in line, he's *Amazing*).

(And it may also be related to the general fact that maybe nowadays filmmakers are more confident of using more metaphorical titles over straight-to-the-point titles than in the past, maybe because we're finally running short of titles? (but this is absolutely unprooved and mere subjective opinion) ;))